# ggmap route finding - doesn't stay on roads

Tags: r, ggmap

I am trying to map a route using the route() function in ggmap. My problem is that the route doesn't stay on the roads. Is there something that my `route_df <- route(origin, destination, structure = "route")` code is missing? Or is there an alternative function that can be used to accomplish this?

Sample code:

```
install_github("rstudio/leaflet")
library(ggmap)
library(leaflet)
way1txt <- "Tinsletown, Vancouver, BC"
way2txt <- "Science World, Vancouver, BC"
route_df <- route(way1txt, way2txt, structure = "route")

# Map using Leaflet R
m = leaflet() %>% addTiles()
m = m %>% addPolylines(route_df$lon, route_df$lat, fill = FALSE)
m = m %>% addPopups(route_df$lon[1], route_df$lat[1], 'Origin')
m = m %>% addPopups(route_df$lon[length(route_df$lon)], 
                    route_df$lat[length(route_df$lon)], 'Destination')
m
```

Screenshot of map:

[image: Screenshot of map with wrong route]

Comment: Just for reference of anyone trying to replicate the code on their machines. You will need [leaflet package](http://www.r-bloggers.com/the-leaflet-package-for-online-mapping-in-r/) to replicate and it is only available on Github: `install_github("rstudio/leaflet")`

Comment: I'll add this. Thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like you are not actually getting the required polylines from `route()` since the default `output=` parameter is set to `simple`. You probably need to change it to `all` as below and start decoding the polylines.

Below is one solution that is based on the `decodeLine()` function taken from [here](http://s4rdd.blogspot.com/2012/12/google-maps-api-decoding-polylines-for.html). Their solution is to define a custom function that decodes polylines and then plot everything it decoded.

```
library(ggmap)
library(leaflet)
way1txt <- "Tinsletown, Vancouver, BC"
way2txt <- "Science World, Vancouver, BC"

route_all <- route(way1txt, way2txt, structure = "route",
                   output = "all")

# Custom decode function
# Taken from http://s4rdd.blogspot.com/2012/12/google-maps-api-decoding-polylines-for.html

decodeLine <- function(encoded){
  require(bitops)

  vlen <- nchar(encoded)
  vindex <- 0
  varray <- NULL
  vlat <- 0
  vlng <- 0

  while(vindex < vlen){
    vb <- NULL
    vshift <- 0
    vresult <- 0
    repeat{
      if(vindex + 1 <= vlen){
        vindex <- vindex + 1
        vb <- as.integer(charToRaw(substr(encoded, vindex, vindex))) - 63  
      }

      vresult <- bitOr(vresult, bitShiftL(bitAnd(vb, 31), vshift))
      vshift <- vshift + 5
      if(vb < 32) break
    }

    dlat <- ifelse(
      bitAnd(vresult, 1)
      , -(bitShiftR(vresult, 1)+1)
      , bitShiftR(vresult, 1)
    )
    vlat <- vlat + dlat

    vshift <- 0
    vresult <- 0
    repeat{
      if(vindex + 1 <= vlen) {
        vindex <- vindex+1
        vb <- as.integer(charToRaw(substr(encoded, vindex, vindex))) - 63        
      }

      vresult <- bitOr(vresult, bitShiftL(bitAnd(vb, 31), vshift))
      vshift <- vshift + 5
      if(vb < 32) break
    }

    dlng <- ifelse(
      bitAnd(vresult, 1)
      , -(bitShiftR(vresult, 1)+1)
      , bitShiftR(vresult, 1)
    )
    vlng <- vlng + dlng

    varray <- rbind(varray, c(vlat * 1e-5, vlng * 1e-5))
  }
  coords <- data.frame(varray)
  names(coords) <- c("lat", "lon")
  coords
}


route_df <- decodeLine( route_all$routes[[1]]$overview_polyline$points )


# Map using Leaflet R
m = leaflet() %>% addTiles()
m = m %>% addPolylines(route_df$lon, route_df$lat, fill = FALSE)
m = m %>% addPopups(route_df$lon[1], route_df$lat[1], 'Origin')
m = m %>% addPopups(route_df$lon[length(route_df$lon)], 
                    route_df$lat[length(route_df$lon)], 'Destination')
m
```

And I get this:

[image]

For reference, there is another `decodeLine` function [here](https://gist.github.com/diegovalle/916889) written by @diegovalle.

Answer (score 1):

You can use my `googleway` package

- get the directions
- decode the polyline (if required)
- plot the route on a Google Map, either as an encoded polyline, or the decoded points

---

```
library(googleway)

apiKey <- 'your_api_key'
mapKey <- 'your_maps_api_key'

res <- google_directions(origin = "Tinsletown, Vancouver, BC", 
                        destination = "Science World, Vancouver, BC",
                        key = apiKey)
```

The polyline is in `res$routes$overview_polyline$points`

You can decode the polyline if you want

```
pl <- res$routes$overview_polyline$points
decode_pl(pl)
#         lat       lon
# 1  49.28025 -123.1076
# 2  49.27969 -123.1076
# 3  49.27823 -123.1076
# 4  49.27711 -123.1077
# 5  49.27707 -123.1043
```

But you don't have to, you can plot the line directly

```
df <- data.frame(polyline = pl)

google_map(key = mapKey, search_box = T) %>%
    add_polylines(data = df, polyline = "polyline")
```

[image]

**Note**

- It looks like the origin doesn't exist or has moved since the question was asked